# Regex doesn't work for the last character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Regex function:

`^[a-zA-Z](?!.*[.'-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?:[.'-][A-Za-z0-9 ]*){0,2}$`

And basically it's supposed to allow only letters/numbers and these special symbols: `.'-` inside of the word. It also detects if there are any consecutive special symbols and if there is `>2` total of them used. For example:

`.asd` (WRONG)

`a.a.a.a` (WRONG)

`a.a.a` (OK)

`blabla.` (WRONG)

`bla.-bla` (WRONG)

`bla-bla` (OK)

It also shouldn't allow special character to be in the front and back of the word. I've managed to do everything but not the special character at the end of the word. I don't know where to put `$` for it to work. Do you have any suggestions? Maybe this formula can be simplified?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect `a!a!a` to be valid, if the only special chars allowed are `.'-`?

Comment: oj yeah, wrong characters, will edit that out

Comment: Change the last `*` to `+`?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?:[.'-][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*){0,2}$`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/USgqBb/1).

Comment: @trincot that was it! thanks!!!

Comment: What about `^(?:\w+[.'-]){0,2}\w+$` - https://regex101.com/r/oCW2LI/1 Not handling any numbers since it is not clear in the examples but is easy to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second half of your regex, where you match a special character, you should require that at least *one* "normal" character follows. So change the `*` in:

```
(?:[.'-][A-Za-z0-9 ]*)
```

...to a `+`:

```
(?:[.'-][A-Za-z0-9 ]+)
```